# How to use Factual API Android driver?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the Factual API Android driver as found at this link with a project:

https://github.com/Factual/factual-java-driver/tree/master-android

I've previously found some Factual jars that aren't compatible with Android, so I presume I need to compile this driver into a jar, but I'm not sure, and I'm having difficulty finding the driver already pre-compiled into a jar.

Does anyone know where I can find pre-compiled android jars, or can point me in the direction of how I should go about compiling this driver into a jar, if that's the best way of using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can download the jar for android

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.factual/factual-java-driver/1.8.2-android